# Why are these bootstrap col elements not stacking in mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, responsiveness

I have these elements in the level at which they are indented. (full html in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gbq538x2/1/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="first" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

    <div id="second" class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3">
    <div id="third" class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
```

I expect the `col-sm-12` inside of the `#first` to stack with `#second` and `#third` however no stacking of elements is occuring on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Trying to make some thing clear to you.**

First of all. Let's have the order of bootstrap 3 in mind (from smallest devices to largest devices): `xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg`

When you now define `col-sm-12` this says nothing else than "take a col `width of 12` for all `sm devices and up`". When defining a `col-anything` all `classes below` will have a `width of 12` too if nothing else if defined.
So **you basically define** `in all sizes take a col width of 12`. It's more understandable to define `col-xs-12` to realize this.

Now have a look at `col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3`. `col-lg-3` will set the column width to `3` for large devices. `col-md-3` will set the column width to `3` for medium devices (and above [but this is overwritten by col-lg]) and `col-xs-3` will set the column width to `3` for smallest devices and above (since `col-md` and `col-lg` are defined, only `col-sm` is set). **Basically you define** `in all sizes thake a col width of 3` which can also be achieved by adding `col-xs-3`. I think what you try to achieve is this:

`col-sm-3` - this would define all `xs` devices with a `width of 12` and all devices `sm and up` with a `width of 3`.

Analog to `col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9` which is a synonym for `col-xs-9`.

Try the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="first" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            A column which has always a size of 12.
        </div>
        <div id="second" class="col-sm-3">
            A column which has a size of 3 for sm-devices and up and a size of 12 for xs-devices (mobile).
        </div>
        <div id="third" class="col-sm-9">
            A column which has a size of 9 for sm-devices and up and a size of 12 for xs-devices (mobile).
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This will realize the following:** For mobile devices you got two rows - one width a 12 width column and one that is deviced into 3 and 9 width. For all bigger devices you to three rows - one full width column for each.